# Using wire:target when emitting an event from outside the component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I previously had this:

```
<div wire:loading wire:target="date_range"></div>
```

where `date_range` was defined by `wire:model` in the same livewire component on a select element.

Because of my app structure, I now update the `date_range` value on a select element through AlpineJS like so, and this is done outside of the livewire component:

```
x-model="date_range" x-on:change="window.livewire.emit('dateRangeChanged', date_range)"
```

I then use an event listener in my Livewire component. This all works as expected, but the problem now is that I want to show the loading state of the element mentioned before, *only* when the `date_range` value is being updated through the global JS event. Is this possible?

The only hacky way I could come up with is that the listener method in the livewire component does something like `$this->date_range_is_loading = true` and set it to false at the end of the render method but that doesn’t feel right.

Answer (score 1):

If this was Vue.js you could do exactly that, i.e. set a `loading` property to `true` before beginning a long-running task and switching it back to `false` after it was done. Unfortunately, since Livewire runs on the server, everything is synchronous, so by the time the request comes back the task will already be complete.

What I ended up doing was reaching for Alpine.js again. Add the following to the root of your Alpine component:

```js
x-data="{ date_range_is_loading: false }"
x-init="
    const alpine = this;
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', () => {
        window.livewire.on('dateRangeChanged', () => alpine.date_range_is_loading = true);
    });
"
```

If you want to listen for Livewire dispatching an action, you can add a listener for the `messageSent` hook.

```js
window.livewire.hook('messageSent', (_, message) => message.actionQueue.forEach(a => {
    if (a.type == 'callMethod' && a.payload.method == 'myAction') {
        alpine.date_range_is_loading = true; // Or whatever you need to do
    }
}))
```